# What is correct here - anyway or either?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, idiomatic-language

A: Have you tried the pills I got you?

B: No.

A: I don't think they go well with alcohol anyway/either.

(B is drinking doing the conversation)

Is "anyway" or "either" correct here?

Comment: What is the meaning you're trying to convey, that "you shouldn't take them with alcohol"? Or "No matter if you haven't tried them yet. You're drinking, and you shouldn't take them with alcohol in any case. Don't try them now."?

Answer (score 0):

"Anyway" should be used.

'Either' cannot be used because speaker A has not mentioned any other alternative to take the pills apart from alcohol.